# Creating filters with couchrest_model

Tags: couchdb

My couchrest_model class has a `design` section which defines a filter, but they never appear.

```
class MyDoc < CouchRest::Model::Base
  property :my_key, String

  design do
    filter 'my_filter', "function(doc) {return (doc['my_key'] == 'value');}"
  end
end
```

If I require the file that contains this in IRB, even if I create a few documents, the filter is never written. What do I need to call to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure couchrest_model supports filters. You could try saving the filter directly with couchrest:

```
@db = CouchRest.database("http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_db")
@db.save_doc({
    "_id" => "_design/my_filters", 
    :filters => {
      :my_filter => {
        "function(doc) {return (doc['my_key'] == 'value');}"
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: It does have a `filter` method in the `Design` class, so I'm assuming it does. However I'm having the same problem with views - they won't generate! Currently I'm using `save_doc` as you suggest. It'll work, but it seems like there should be another way!

Comment: I also think there should be another way. However, I've never seen any examples of lists, updates or filters in the couchrest_model documentation and that makes me suspect they are not well supported. Also, views work not so well with active model. Sometimes they are not created and I don't know why.